# is there a Java or C# library for mining bitcoins?

Tags: development, mining-software

Hi guys is there a Java or C# library for **mining** bitcoins? I am hoping to incorporate it into an application. I have read the other questions that asked about libraries but i need to know if these libraries allow mining

Comment: For which aspect of mining? Why not use one of the existing programs, like guiminer or pyoclbm?

Answer (score 2):

[Diablo Miner](https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner) is GPU miner implemented in Java. It's not a library, but it shouldn't be hard to incorporate it's code in another application.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Bitcoin C# implementation [here](http://bitcoincs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)